# Error while installing gauge js plugin in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, getgauge

Seeing an error while installing getgauge js plugin in docker image

I am trying to create an image with all tools that is used to run my suite and then push it to docker repo so that I dont need to build the image every time when I run the suite

Here is the dockerfile I use to build image

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-nodejs8.10
ENV NODE_PATH=./node_modules/:/var/lang/lib/node_modules
RUN npm install -g selenium-webdriver
RUN npm install  -g @getgauge/cli
RUN gauge install js
RUN gauge install json-report
RUN gauge install html-report
RUN gauge  install screenshot
RUN npm install -g superagent
RUN npm install -g  xlsx
RUN useradd jenkins -u 2000 -ms /bin/bash -d /home/jenkins
USER jenkins
WORKDIR /workspace
```

Then simply run `docker build .` from the same folder of dockerfile

and I get a an error in the step when it is trying to install js plugin using `gauge install js` command

```
Step 5/15 : RUN npm install  -g @getgauge/cli
 ---> Running in 58ff0c551dd7
/var/lang/bin/gauge -> /var/lang/lib/node_modules/@getgauge/cli/bin/gauge

> @getgauge/cli@1.0.6 install /var/lang/lib/node_modules/@getgauge/cli
> node ./src/index.js

Fetching download url for Gauge version 1.0.6
Downloading https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/releases/download/v1.0.6/gauge-1.0.6-linux.x86_64.zip to ./bin
+ @getgauge/cli@1.0.6
added 83 packages in 13.099s
Removing intermediate container 58ff0c551dd7
 ---> 563ea8be6d39
Step 6/15 : RUN gauge install js
 ---> Running in cf7c3e7899ee

Telemetry
---------

This installation of Gauge collects usage data in order to help us improve your experience.
The data is anonymous and doesn't include command-line arguments.
To turn this message off opt in or out by running 'gauge telemetry on' or 'gauge telemetry off'.

Read more about Gauge telemetry at https://gauge.org/telemetry


2019/11/07 22:06:00 Failed to get configuration from Gauge properties file. Error: open /root/.gauge/config/gauge.properties: no such file or directory
.........
[grpc] Success: "/tmp/gauge_temp1573164361831732000/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote
added 181 packages in 6.963s
Successfully installed plugin 'js' version 2.3.5
```

This is what I am curious about - **2019/11/07 22:06:00 Failed to get configuration from Gauge properties file. Error: open /root/.gauge/config/gauge.properties: no such file or directory**

Even with error it finish successful ..

Answer (score 0):

Gauge tries to read some global properties from `~/.gauge/config/gauge.properties` file. If there is no file exists or some error while getting the properties from the file. it logs the warning with `Failed to get configuration from Gauge properties file` and use the default properties.

Look the [docs](https://docs.gauge.org/configuration.html) to configure the gauge properties.